PytubeFix and others libraries doesnt work very well
When I download in 'highest resolution', the video always downloads in 640x360, no matter how I "reformulate" it.
I think maybe it is downloading this preview:
previewing a video on the youtube homepage
from pytubefix import YouTube

video = "https://youtu.be/NI9LXzo0UY0?si=_Jy_CzN-QwI4SOkC"

def Download(link):
    youtube_object = YouTube(link)
    youtube_object = youtube_object.streams.get_highest_resolution()
    try:
        youtube_object.download()
    except:
        print("An error has occurred")
    print("Download is completed successfully")


Download(video)

I try using three libraries:

pytube (discontinued)
pytubefix
yt_dlp

All downloads in 360p and I expect the highest possible quality, normally 1080p
